# send_keys speed is very slow selenium | python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I am using chrome 32 bit on windows 10. Selenium **send_keys()** has slow type speed. It gets **linear time** worst for the longer character strings. Please Suggest me how to speed up send_keys() typing speed or suggest me an **alternate way** to type text in the text section.

```
txt_box=driver.find_element(By.XPATH  , '//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]')
my_string="john"
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '" + my_string +"')", txt_box)
```

This alternate way not works.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: do you have to type the text? Otherwise it is a bit hackish and does not test everything, but I think you can executescript to set the value.

Comment: Please update code trials in your question.

Comment: @JeremyKahan send_key() works on txt_box but execute_script not working

Comment: Here is a Protractor line that is working on a textarea for me (there were 2 on screen, I located the first), where the items was very long and took minutes to key in. await browser.executeScript(
            "arguments[0].value=arguments[1].toString()",
            textareas[0],
            ilObjectAsString
          );

Comment: @JeremyKahanI know it is dumb to ask but can i get the python code

Comment: I'm no Python expert, but I can think on it. Also, the next line of mine may be necessary in your case: await element
            .all(by.tagName("textarea"))
            .first()
            .sendKeys(" " + Key.BACK_SPACE); //need to do this to trigger field changes to be processed

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368547/selenium-python-bindings-how-to-execute-javascript-on-an-element for Python implementation

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using 64-bit OS architecture on my PC - as far as I remember is because Selenium performs switching between 32-bit and 64-bit mode (which is very slow operation). ChromeDriver was supported only in 32-bit. I had same issues with IE driver too.

Even, if was confirmed in the [Chromedriver issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1797#c1)

> > Yes, Chromedriver works on 64-bit Windows and against 64-bit Chrome successfully.

I would suggest that you should check the driver-browser pair compatibility from the [Download page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). In case yours are ok, try a version up/down for both (they overlap).

Comment: I checked it works with the same speed in firefox 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in python, tried all those 32-bit, 64-bit stuff with different browsers but send_keys() was taking incredibly long time and felt like an old grumpy man typing. I found the solution to use Javascript and boom that made a huge impact. Here is how you go around with using Javascript.

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("content").value="My Dummy Text";')
```

Where:

Driver is your browser driver that you created using the below similar command:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_path)
```

execute_script is the function we'll use to pass the Javascript

document.getElementByID is your JS method using which you are going to grab the textbox/textarea information, in this case, since, we are using getElementByID, therefore you have to find the ID of the textbox, in my case it was "content", see reference below:

```
<textarea class="wp-editor-area" style="height: 361px; margin-top: 37px;" autocomplete="off" cols="40" name="content" id="content" aria-hidden="false"></textarea>
```

Notice the ID parameter of the above HTML textarea tag. You can find this information using Chrome Developer tools by performing right click and Inspect and then copying the element and then checking the ID information. If for some reason, ID is not present, you can use other methods such as 'Class' or 'Name' or 'CSS' etc. for getElementBy*

Refer to this link for more information : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp

Finally, you are throwing in your content into that textbox using the .value parameter. In our case, we are passing the text "My Dummy Text" as a value to textbox and it works absolutely fine.

Hope this helps anyone looking to speed up send_keys() in python

Note: This method will replace all the existing text in the textarea, if you would like to preserve the existing text, then you can first 'get' the element value, append to your string and then pass the value method and that should work fine.