# Selenium/BS4 JS execute raises "Message: TypeError: arguments[0].setAttribute is not a function"

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am using Selenium with BS4 to grab elements on a page and I want to use JS Execute_script to put a border around the element. However I am getting this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: TypeError: arguments[0].setAttribute is not a function
```

I've found this: [Selenium Python bindings: how to execute JavaScript on an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368547/selenium-python-bindings-how-to-execute-javascript-on-an-element)

[I based it off this solution](https://seleniumwithjavapython.wordpress.com/selenium-with-python/intermediate-topics/playing-with-javascript-and-javascript-executor/highlighting-a-web-element-on-webpage/), which I got working when I grabbed the element using the Selenium - find_element_by_ID. It seems to be a different object type when getting an element as a soup object maybe?

P.S. when the object is not a string type its a `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`

Which raises a separate exception.

Any ideas, maybe I should go back to getting the elements through Selenium?

EDIT:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('"https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?suggestCount=0suggestChosen=false&clickSource=searchBtn&typedKeyword=&sc.keyword=&locT=C&locId=1132348&jobType="')

innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")     
soup = BeautifulSoup(innerHTML)

browser.implicitly_wait(10)

def highlight_element():
    #Use to highlight element selected
    elem = soup.findAll("li", {"class": "jl"})

    def apply_style():
      browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','border: 4px solid red');", str(elem[0]))

apply_style()
```

Comment: How are you getting bs4 element, using find/find_all? Please share the logic that you used in your code.

Comment: Can you include your code and ideally the url, otherwise share html using snippet tool via [edit].

Comment: @supputuri added code to show how I am getting the element.

Comment: @QHarr Added code and URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested with Chrome. I pass the browser and WebElement to the function and use find_element so no index required. Notice that `elem` is a webElement.

```
from selenium import webdriver

def apply_style(browser, elem):
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','border: 4px solid red');", elem)

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?suggestCount=0suggestChosen=false&clickSource=searchBtn&typedKeyword=&sc.keyword=&locT=C&locId=1132348&jobType=')
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
apply_style(browser, browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.jl'))
```